# How to make JMeter read unique values from a csv

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am running a JMeter test which requires me to use a value only once. If i use that value again the test will fail. As of now I am reading these value from a CSV and I have noticed that JMeter is neither reading these values in a sequence nor using the value only once.

These values have been provided by another team which will use these values in their test once I have successfully used them in mine and they need the value to be in sequence so even if I let JMeter do its thing i can't give the other team number because they are not in sequence.

I know in Loadrunner you can do this but now sure how to do it in JMeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Assume you use "csv data set config" for Parameterization. You should use below settings.
Recycle on EOF: false,
Stop thread on EOF: True,
Sharing mode: All thread.

This setting is similar to that of unique, each iteration, continue with last value, abort vuser at EOF in loadrunner.

Comment: That is correct with the exception of Sharing Mode. I have it set to current thread Group and I am running multiple thread groups at the same time. This does not ensure that the value are picked up sequentially.

Comment: With this setting- data will be picked up in the order of thread creation. Thread1 will take 1st value, thread2 will take second value and so on..